# How we write own function in swift with completionHandler

Tags: swift, completionhandler

in objective c i write a method

-(void)loginApi:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict completion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *json,BOOL sucess))completion {

how we  write same method

Comment: Please make the question more precise.

Answer (score 1):

```
    func loginApi(dict: NSMutableDictionary, completion: (json:NSDictionary,success: Bool) -> Void){
    //Do whatever you want to do here
    completion(json: dict, success: true) //This is just an example of how you can call
    }
```

Give this a try. I think it should work. If not,let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
func loginApi(completion : (json: [Dictionary<String, String>, success: Bool]) -> [Dictionary<String Int>]) {
    ...
    completion(...)
}
```

Comment: If all you're going to do is a no-explanation code dump, it could at least compile and match the signature of the method in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although Previous answers will work I would suggest to *alias* it instead of typing the declaration every time (it also concern Objective c).

```
 typealias CompletionHandlerType = (error:NSError ,response:AnyObject?) -> Void
```